# Visio to generate JSON documents

Tags: json, visio

My enterprise is taking its first steps into the NoSQL world (CouchDB).  Since we have thousands of developers spread over 8 states and 2 countries, documentation is very important to us.  Typically, in the RDBMS world, we would do the developer documentation in Visio.  Its worked great for 20 years and we have that very well refined.

I see that modeling a NoSQL schema using Visio's UML tools seems to be a very popular thing to do.  Is there a way to export Visio's UML model to a JSON representation?

EDIT:--

I have been doing research and i found json-schema.org and http://jsonschema.net

If there is a generic macro out there somewhere that can export the UML into something like xml, I can take that and modify it to generate json schema files.  those sound like the perfect solution for my needs.

Comment: Hi, did you find any tools to assist you in this process @scphantm?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there are not many tools developed out there for this purpose.

But what really matters is how should the JSON look like?

There isn't any standard for representing UML class diagrams in JSON.